Certificate rotation for SSLBundles with Jetty
I'm using Spring 3 with jetty for my server. In Spring-boot 3.3, SSLStoreProvider was removed, in favor of using SSLBundles. Using SSLBundles did work for initial SSL setup, but the hot-reload option for SSLBundles is only supported for tomcat and netty.
I did try setting the reload-on-update tag in application.properties, but to no avail. I'm not able to find any resource which explains how I can perform certificate rotation for SSLBundles without restarting the application. Any help is appreciated

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
